# Как правильно перебрать массив?

Tags: php

Не пускаю на сайт подозрительных ботов, написал маленький скрипт, но выглядит он как то не очень, возможно есть другой способ перебора массива?

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$bot = array("MJ12bot","MSIE","AhrefsBot");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
            $check = strripos($user_agent, $bot[$i]);
            if ($check === false) {
                echo " ";
            }
            else {
                die('Боты, валите отсюда!');
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Например так:**

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$bots = array("MJ12bot","MSIE","AhrefsBot");
foreach ($bots as $bot){
    if (!strripos($user_agent, $bot))
         die('Боты, валите отсюда!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно вместо `i <= 2` поставить `i < count($bot)` или `i < sizeof($bot)` - тогда можно не менять 2 на количество элементов в массиве -1. Или можно просто использовать `foreach($bot as $str)` и тогда в каждой итерации имя бота будет в `$str`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, было бы проще закрыть через robots.txt:

```
User-agent: AhrefsBot
Disallow: /

User-agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /
```

`Ahrefs` нормальный бот, будет учитывать [robots](https://ru.ahrefs.com/robot). Насчёт `MJ12bot` не уверен, но скорее всего тоже будет. `MSIE` непонятный, скорее всего ему плевать на правила.

Ну и помните, что при желании боты могут всегда представиться нормальным юзер-агентом. Так что тут уже смотреть по ip и количеству запросов.